# Is there any way to hook whole drawing functions for a process under windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, directx, hook, render

I want to capture everything what a window displays. On the other hand, it will be very nice if that window doesn't actually display nothing on the screen. How? The process will call drawing functions, my function will hook and draw it to somewhere else (for example into a bitmap file) and return without actually drawing on screen.

What I know is, in Windows NT architecture, every thread has a system call table and you can change system call table of a single thread (or just set it in the beginning) to your functions. By only changing drawing api (GDI?) (i am not sure how I would survive if application uses directx rendering but maybe there is a way) i feel that I can do it. Can I? What should I do if the application uses DirectX rendering?

Thanks in advance,

Ali Veli

Comment: Does that refer to a window in an application that you write, or to a window in "any existing application"? In the first case, you would not necessarily need a hook at all. In the second case, it's a daunting task to say the least.

Comment: In that case, the least intrusive and least offensive thing to do would be to write your own gdi32 wrapper DLL that exports the same functions as the original and optionally forwards the functions (similar to how tools like e.g. GLIntercept work). You can then repeat any draw commands in a DC of your own. Alternatively, you could try to inject code that creates an own DC inside the other application and replaces the normal one with this one, and later read the process memory, but meh... good luck with that. Tampering with the system call tables... again, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up hooking only CreateDC-like functions, made it always creating a memory device context and letting all other functions draw on that memory DC.